# Twilio - programmatically taking incoming call

Tags: twilio

I am making an app with Twilio API to build a feature to track the call/sms statuses on UI.

For example, if I call to a Twilio number from my phone, on the UI the call status of the number will be dynamically changes.

But currently, as soon as i make an incoming call to the Twilio number, it received the call.

Is there any way that I can make the Twilio phone number take the incoming call programmatically? Just like the way we can hang up the call programmatically.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a webhook URL in Twilio account where you can configure your endpoint  programmatically

[image: I have provided the screenshot below]

Comment: I know this part. but the problem is when the number receives an inbound call, it will automatically pick up the call. What I would like to have is to pick up the call programmatically.

Comment: You have to provide your API Endpoint in Webhook to pick up the call programmatically.